# How to nest data to child>child>child component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a structure:

- Root component
- - buttons
- - - (menu search component) - a simple input field
- - Widgets
- - - (widget component )
- - - - (Cats widget) - displays what I put in menu search here.

How I pass data from menu search component to widget component?
User insert data in input field and I would like to displat in the widget field.

Do I have to call the event emitter from menu search and pass the data to buttons, and than go done widgets>Widget Child> cats component to display?

If so how do I correct pass the data? Espciall how do I pass the data downwards?

What I've currently done is used @Output to pass the data from cats to widgets, from widgets to root app.

To pass from child event I did

```
@Output() inputData: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
customFunction(event){
    this.inputData.emit(event);
}
```

Than on the parent catch the event

```
<cats (inputData)="colorChange($event)"></cats>
```

until I reached Root component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular guide has a bunch of tips around handling various component to component data interaction scenarios like this one.

The basic options are to chain property and output bindings between the intermediate components, use dependency injection and ViewChild decorators to 'jump' the view hierarchy and grab instances of your 'higher level' components from lower ones (dependency injection) or vice versa (ViewChild), or the use of services to pass data around (probably the best option in more varied situations due to less coupling to the view hierarchy).

[See the angular docs for more info.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: I have not yet understood how is service used to pass data, as I thought service is just block of scripts to execute but can't actual store data.
I have seen ViewChild, as you use when you get grandparents data to child for example.  PS. Angular docs for me are very hard to read, as it is complicated written and feels like bits are missing to understand the full concept.

Comment: with a service can you pass data from grandparent to child after everything is load also? Or is it only when the constructor is launched to pre set the data?